# Как создавать кнопки динамически?

Tags: java, swing, gui, button

Подскажите как создать кнопки в jPanel при нажатии другой кнопки. (Нажимаю кнопку, и на jPanel создается новая кнопка jButton1, нажимаю еще раз jButton2, и т.д.)

Вот кнопки теперь создаются. И вот возник еще вопрос "Как унаследовать данные из существующей кнопки в динамически созданную?"

Comment: Так же как и не динамически. В чем сложность? Где застряли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если надо программно, то вот так

```
    JButton button = new JButton("Test");
    button.setSize(100, 100);
    jPanel1.add(button);
    jPanel1.repaint();
```

Скорее всего Вы так и делали. Хитрость в том, чтобы установить размер кнопки(setSize). По умолчанию он равен 0х0

**P.S.** данный код следует поместить в событие нажатия кнопки. Его можно автоматически создать в `Netbeans` посредством двойного клика по кнопке

**P.P.S** таже учтите, если не выставлять координаты новой кнопки, то она будет отображатся "под" первой созданной. Для избежание подобного надо устанавливать, к примеру, `button.setBounds(x += 10, y += 10, 100, 100);`, где `x` и `y` - это поля класса с изначальными координатами(для первой кнопки)

Comment: Почему эта кнопка появляется когда на нее наводишь?

Comment: Всмысле? Сразу не отображается? А. Добавил перерисовку(`repaint`)

Comment: сейчас работает